# ANOVA as Multiple Linear Regression - variance due to different factors and interactions

Tags: regression, anova, python

I am doing a 2-way anova with repetitions, but the number of repetitions is not always the same.
[image: in some cells, only 2 reps, for example in row B, column 8]

So I am using multiple linear regression with dummy variables. When testing for the interaction effect, i construct a reduced model, that is the beta's where some dummy variables are multiplied (t_1*t_2)     are set to zero. Then I construct the F statistic and test against a critical value.

```
# reduced model
X_reduced_inter = np.transpose(np.vstack((ones, parts, levels)))
beta_reduced_inter, residuals_reduced_inter =  np.linalg.lstsq(X_reduced_inter, all_values, rcond=None)[0:2]
df_reduced_inter = len(all_values) - len(beta_reduced_inter)

F_stat_up = (residuals_reduced_inter - residuals_full) / (df_reduced_inter - df_full)
F_stat_down = residuals_full / df_full

F_stat = F_stat_up / F_stat_down

c_interactions = f.ppf(1-alpha, df_reduced_inter - df_full, df_full)
if F_stat > c_interaction:
  # interactions are significant
```

If the interactions are significant, what is the variance due to interactions? 
    is it

```
f.stats(df_reduced_inter - df_full, df_full, moments='v')
```

(variance of a F random varibale with the corresponding df?)
    also in that case, if i want to know the variance due to row factor, do I need to construct another reduced model, i.e. set all betas that multiply the right dummy variables to zero and find the variance in a similar way like for interactions?

```
X_reduced_rows = np.transpose(np.vstack((ones, columns, mixed)))
beta_reduced_rows, residuals_reduced_rows = np.linalg.lstsq(X_reduced_rows, all_values, rcond=None)[0:2]
df_reduced_rows = len(all_values) - len(beta_reduced_rows)
var_rows = f.stats(df_reduced_rows - df_full, df_full, moments='v')
```

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated. What do you mean by "repetitions"?

Comment: I am sorry the right term is replication?

Comment: I am not sure what the right term is, as I am not sure what you are trying to say.

Comment: I am talking about two-way ANOVA with replication. I think that's clear from the table I posted? There are 2 factors - row factor with 3 levels A,B and C, and column factor with 10 levels, and each cell has three or two observations, hence the replications. Since there are replications we can test for the interaction effect. But the number of replications in each cell is not the same (two or three) hence the standard ANOVA is done via multiple linear regression with categorical "dummy" variables;

Comment: (cont.) the equation starts like beta_0 + beta_1 * is_level_B + beta_2 * is_level_C + ... etc. what part of my question is unclear?

Comment: ANOVA is  the same as regression.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I said in my comment "the standard ANOVA is done via multiple linear regression with categorical "dummy" variables". If it wasn't the same, one couldn't be done "via" the other. I posted a reply to my own question.

Answer (score 0):

Replying to my own question.

From the code I posted in the question, F_stat_up / F_stat_down is taken from here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-test (see Regression problems).

The F_stat_up (numerator) is MS_interactions in the standard Two-way ANOVA with replications. The F_stat_down (denominator) is MS_error.

In the Two-way ANOVA with replications procedure the estimate of variance due to interactions is computed as (MS_interactions - MS_error) / m, where m is the number of observations in a cell (in the balanced case, it's always the same).

There is a way to re-express this formula, so that it doesn't depend on m. Because the degrees of freedom for error can be either rc(m-1) or n - rc, so with a bit of algebra, m = n/rc, where

r ... # of levels of the row factor

c ... # of levels of the column factor

m ... # of repetitions per cell (balanced case)

n ... # of all observed values

I wanted to find the estimate of variance due to row factor. I need to construct another reduced model, the design matrix X will only have columns (referring to code from my question, where parts refers to column factor):

```
X_reduced_rows = np.transpose(np.vstack((ones, parts))) 
beta_reduced_rows, residuals_reduced_rows = 
np.linalg.lstsq(X_reduced_rows, all_values, rcond=None)[0:2]
df_reduced_rows = len(all_values) - len(beta_reduced_rows)
MS_rows = (residuals_reduced_rows - residuals_reduced_inter) / (df_reduced_rows - df_reduced_inter)
```

Now having found MS_rows, the estimate of variance due to row factor is
(MS_rows - MS_interactions) / (c (n/rc))

Notice that this doesn't depend on number of observations in a cell, hence we can use it even in the unbalanced case.

References: http://www.real-statistics.com/two-way-anova/two-factor-anova-with-replication/